# In quaternion why $i j k = -1$ and not for example $i j k = 1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, quaternions, noncommutative-algebra

The rotations around axes appear to be commutative. If I perform a $180^{\circ}$ rotation around the $x$-axis and then another rotation around the $y$-axis, I obtain:

Rotation around the $x$-axis: $$x,\, y,\, z \Rightarrow x,\, -y,\, -z$$
Rotation around the $y$-axis: $$x,\, -y,\, -z \Rightarrow -x,\, -y,\, z$$
However, if I reverse the order and rotate $180^{\circ}$ around the $y$-axis first and then around the $x$-axis, I still get the same result:

Rotation around the $y$-axis: $$x,\, y,\, z \Rightarrow -x,\, y,\, -z$$
Rotation around the $x$-axis: $$-x,\, y,\, -z \Rightarrow -x,\, -y,\, z$$
As you can see, the composition of rotations is commutative. In quaternion algebra, quaternion multiplication is defined as the composition of rotations. But based on what we have seen above, it is not necessary for this multiplication to be non-commutative, as the composition of rotations in practice is not.

However, I have read that in order to maintain the consistent algebraic structure of quaternions, Hamilton formulated:
$i^{2} = j^{2} = k^{2} = i j k = -1$

Where $i j k = -1$ precisely because multiplication should not be commutative. It is not clear to me why the non-commutativity of quaternion multiplication arises from this definition ($i j k = -1$), nor why this non-commutativity is necessary despite not being observed in practice. Is there something that I am missing or have not understood well? What led Hamilton to understand that $i j k = -1$?

Comment: Non-commutative means "not always commutative", not "always not commutative".

Comment: Some rotations have diagonal matrices.  All diagonal matrices commute.  You could put the  quaternions in the order $j,i,k$, and would have $j^2=i^2=k^2=-1,jik=1$

Comment: Note that the interpretation of "basic quaternions as rotations" needs to be done in four dimensions.  In three dimensions, this concept would make something like $i^2=-1$ impossible as it effectively would say we can turn an object inside-out by doing two rotations.  To get 3D rigid-body rotations out of it, we have to factor out one of those dimensions.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Do you mean that in three dimensions you only have two bases, so there are no simple rotations along the axes?

Comment: No.  Of course there are rotations about the axes in any dimension.  I am saying that you can't find any rotation $T$ in three-dimensional real space such that $T^2x = -x$ for every $x$.  This is only possible in even-numbered dimensions as in odd-numbered dimensions, $-1$ turns an object inside-out.

Comment: More directly to your question, though, no sequence of rotations in 3D can give $-1$.  The equations $i^2=j^2=k^2=ijk=-1$ need to be interpreted in $4D$ real space if you're representing them by rotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### Rotation

If you use the vector / quaternion $r$ as the axis of rotation, $\varphi$ as the rotation angle, $\mathrm{v}$ as the vector to be rotated and the rotated vector $\mathrm{v}_{\text{rotated}}$, then the formula applies:
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{v}_{\text{rotated}} &= \mathrm{q} \cdot \mathrm{v} \cdot \overline{\mathrm{q}}\\
\mathrm{v}_{\text{rotated}} &= \left( \cos\left( \frac{\varphi}{2} \right) + \mathrm{u} \cdot \sin\left( \frac{\varphi}{2} \right) \right) \cdot \mathrm{v} \cdot \left( \cos\left( \frac{\varphi}{2} \right) - \mathrm{u} \cdot \sin\left( \frac{\varphi}{2} \right) \right)\\
\mathrm{v}_{\text{rotated}} &= \left( \cos\left( \frac{\varphi}{2} \right) + \frac{\mathrm{r}}{||\mathrm{r}||} \cdot \sin\left( \frac{\varphi}{2} \right) \right) \cdot \mathrm{v} \cdot \left( \cos\left( \frac{\varphi}{2} \right) - \frac{\mathrm{r}}{||\mathrm{r}||} \cdot \sin\left( \frac{\varphi}{2} \right) \right)\\
\end{align*}
$$

However, this formula is only always true if $i \cdot j \cdot k = -1$ (Hemilton's definition). The important thing here is "always". If we only do rotations of $\varphi = g \cdot 180^{\circ} \wedge g \in \mathbb{Z}$ then it doesn't matter which axis we rotate around first, which is why you don't emphasize the importance of the in your examples see order (or the non-comutativity). The rotation around the $y$ axis with the formula:

$$
\begin{align*}
x' \cdot i + y' \cdot j + z' \cdot k &= \left( \cos\left( \frac{180^{\circ}}{2} \right) + \sin\left( \frac{180^{\circ}}{2} \right) \cdot j \right) \cdot \left( x \cdot i + y \cdot j + z \cdot k \right) \cdot \left( \cos\left( \frac{180^{\circ}}{2} \right) - \sin\left( \frac{180^{\circ}}{2} \right) \cdot j \right)\\
x' \cdot i + y' \cdot j + z' \cdot k &= \left( \cos\left( 90^{\circ} \right) + \sin\left( 90^{\circ} \right) \cdot j \right) \cdot \left( x \cdot i + y \cdot j + z \cdot k \right) \cdot \left( \cos\left( 90^{\circ} \right) - \sin\left( 90^{\circ} \right) \cdot j \right)\\
x' \cdot i + y' \cdot j + z' \cdot k &= \left( 0 + 1 \cdot j \right) \cdot \left( x \cdot i + y \cdot j + z \cdot k \right) \cdot \left( 0 - 1 \cdot j \right)\\
x' \cdot i + y' \cdot j + z' \cdot k &= \left( x \cdot j \cdot i + y \cdot j \cdot j + z \cdot j \cdot k \right) \cdot \left( 0 - 1 \cdot j \right)\\
x' \cdot i + y' \cdot j + z' \cdot k &= \left( -x \cdot k - y + z \cdot i \right) \cdot \left( 0 - 1 \cdot j \right)\\
x' \cdot i + y' \cdot j + z' \cdot k &= \left( x \cdot k \cdot j + y \cdot j - z \cdot i \cdot j \right)\\
x' \cdot i + y' \cdot j + z' \cdot k &= \left( -x \cdot i + y \cdot j - z \cdot k \right)\\
x' \cdot i + y' \cdot j + z' \cdot k &= -x \cdot i + y \cdot j - z \cdot k\\
\end{align*}
$$

However, the whole thing changes for all $\varphi \ne g \cdot 180^{\circ} \wedge g \in \mathbb{Z}$.

A plot of rotation of quternion $q = i + j + k$ by $45^{\circ}$ around $x$-axis first and $y$-axis second (pink points) and around $y$-axis first and $x$-axis second (purple points) where $q' =$ first rotation and $q'' =$ second rotation:

[image]

The red axis is the $\color{red}{x}$-axis, green axis is the $\color{green}{y}$-axis and blue axis is the $\color{blue}{z}$-axis. The green circle is the circle of the second rotation and the red one is the circle of the first rotation.

###### Other Definition

Carl Friedrich Gauß had the imaginary units of the quaternions with $i \circ j \circ k = + 1$ defined. With this we would get the "Gegenring" of the quaternion $\mathbb{Q} = \left( \mathbb{R}^{4},\, +,\, \cdot \right)$ aka $\mathbb{Q}^{op} = \left( \mathbb{R}^{4},\, +,\, \circ \right)$. It's still not commutative here, but here we have the $+1$.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why $ijk=−1$ and not $ijk=1$ is a consequence of the non-commutativity of quaternion multiplication. If we were to assume $ijk=1$, then this would imply that quaternion multiplication is commutative, which is not the case.
the multiplication of $i, j, k$ is defined as:
$ij=k$,
$jk=i$,
$ki=j$,
$ji=−k$,
$kj=−i$,
$ik=−j$.
From these multiplication rules, we can see that $ijk=i(jk)=i(i)=−1$.

Comment: So, did Hamilton derive ijk = -1 by considering the pairwise multiplications of i, j, and k, and not the other way around?

Comment: Yes. Hamilton was looking for a system of numbers that extended the complex numbers and allowed for three-dimensional rotations. He started with the assumption that the product of two distinct basis elements would be a linear combination of the three basis elements. By considering all possible combinations, Hamilton found that the multiplication rules I mentioned earlier satisfied the desired properties. Hamilton derive ijk = -1 by considering the pairwise multiplications of i, j, and k.

Comment: The paper On a new Species of Imaginary Quantities connected with a theory of Quaternions is Hamilton's first paper on quaternions. It was read at the meeting of the Royal Irish Academy on November 13th, 1843, and is included in Vol. 2 of the Proceedings of the Royal Irish Academy.

Comment: Just one last question. Does the minus sign next to the imaginary units, as in the case of -k in ji = -k, represent a rotation in the opposite direction around the k-axis? Should it be interpreted as -1k where -1 is the quaternion with a real part of -1 and a=b=c=0?

Comment: @Huntwer Either works.  It should more definitionally be $-k = (-1)k$, but $k^2=-1$ implies $k^{-1} = -k$, so it also is the reverse rotation of $k$.

Answer (score 1):

Your computations do not show that the composition of rotations around the axes is commutative. All that they show is that the composition of half-turns around the axes are commutative. However, if you consider rotations of, say, a quarter of a turn, then they will not commute.

Comment: Actually, by performing operations by rotating 90 degrees, the compositions are not commutative. Therefore, do the bases i, j, and k indicate rotations of 90 degrees around the axes?

Comment: I don't know what is the process by which you associate to each quaternion $q$ a rotation in $3$-dimensional space, but the usual way is this: we consider the space $H$ of all pure quaternions (that is, those quaternions whose real part is $0$) and the map from $H$ into itself defined by $r\mapsto q.r.q^*$, where $q^*$ is the conjugate of $q$. Then, if $q$ is equal to $i$, what we have is a half-turn around the $i$-axes. And we have a similar thing with $j$ and with $k$.

Answer (score 1):

Quaternion rotation by   $q$  carries $x i+y j +z k$ to $q^{-1}(x i+y j +z k)q$.

Now if you work this out with $q=i$ you will see that if we had $i^2=+1$ we'd get $x i+y j +z k$ carried to $-x i+y j+ z k$ whereas we want it to be carried to $x i -y j -z k$.

Comment: I may be wrong but I think that there is something wrong in your solution:
$$
\begin{align*}
(xi+yj+zk)'&=i^{-1}(xi+yj+zk)i\\
(xi+yj+zk)'&=-i(xi+yjzk)i\\
(xi+yj+zk)'&=(-xi^2-yij-zik)i\\
(xi+yj+zk)'&=(x-yk+zj)i\\
(xi+yj+zk)'&=(xi-yki+zji)\\
(xi+yj+zk)'&=(xi-yj-zk)\\
\end{align*}
$$
So your example would be wrong. I might have misunderstood something...

Comment: @KevinDietrich I think your calculation uses the [correct] $i^2=-1$ so gets the correct answer: but using $i^2=+1$ gets it wrong.